# string search using awk

Tags: files, awk, grep

I have file-1 which has list of transaction id .

File -1

```
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|10.233.18.29.677220869928387637969                
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|11.233.18.29.677220869928387637969                   
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|12.233.18.29.677220869928387637969
```

I have a file-2 which has the logs .It can have pipes in other place .So pipe cannot be used as delimiter

File-2

```
logline-1|somefield fdfdsff dfwwtwtwt **201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|12.233.18.29.677220869928387637969**
logline-2|somefield fdfdsff dfwwtwtwt **201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|12.233.18.29.677220869928387637969**
logline-3|somefield fdfdsff dfwwtwtwt **201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|10.233.18.29.677220869928387637969**
logline-4|somefield fdfdsff dfwwtwtwt **201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|10.233.18.29.677220869928387637969**
logline-5|somefield fdfdsff dfwwtwtwt **201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|11.233.18.29.677220869928387637969**
```

How can i use awk to read all contents in file-1 ... grep on file 2 and create a file 3 which has (transaction id - occurrences in file 2)

Expected File-3

```
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|10.233.18.29.677220869928387637969     2
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|11.233.18.29.677220869928387637969     1
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|12.233.18.29.677220869928387637969     2
```

Comment: I  add values from the other question. thoses strings are more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with awk:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { v[$1] = 0; next; } { v[$4]++; } END { for (elem in v) { print elem, v[elem]; } }' File-1 File-2 >outfile
```

So result will be:

```
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|11.233.18.29.677220869928387637969 1
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|12.233.18.29.677220869928387637969 2
201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|10.233.18.29.677220869928387637969 2
```

But again I do not know why you need 2 files. You can do it with File-2:

```
awk '{ v[$4]++; } END { for (elem in v) { print elem, v[elem]; } }' File-2 >outfile
```

Result will be the same.

Comment: sorry for the typo in my file-2 .There is not really a space in between tranid-3 .But isnt there a way where i don't have to mention the search strings position in file-2 .

Comment: Then you should try the first one. And why you nedd 2 files?

Comment: Probably i should be more specific ..  

My transaction id looks like : "201503301616|9b8791b3-f860-409f-aad0-24debf834c1b|10.233.18.29.677220869928387637969"  

and my file 2 can have pipes in other field too .(So i cannot use pipe as delimiter to perfectly extract transaction id )So i would need to do somthing like |grep wc-l

Comment: If it does not help, you can edit the question and I think someone could help. I can delete this answer as irrelevant.

Comment: the answers seems to fit with new value (double star was used to bold other question).

Comment: @Archemar thanks, I edited it and removed unimportant part.